# when window.body.scrollTop is set?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll, swt, anchor

The context:

I have the following stack: IE10 + SWT + Java (with browser caching disabled). And I want to be able to cache myself the scroll position of some html files from my Java app.

I have the following flow:

1. I do a `setUrl()` on my SWT browser with a html file;
2. In that html file I have a JS callback to Java on: `$(document).ready()`;
3. From Java I do a `window.scroll(0, some_cached_scroll_possition)` on the SWT browser instance;

This works quite fine until url's with anchors are used. In this case I expect that the scroll position to be moved to the appropriate anchor location before `$(document).ready()` occurs. But from what I understand until now, it seems that this happens concurrently with the `$(document).ready()` event. And this blows my mind ..

Putting a delay in `$(document).ready()` before the Java callback shows me that I can't rely on this event if I want to change the scroll position.

My questions: is there any other event that occurs for sure after the page was fully loaded?
Other suggestions are also welcomed.

Could you recommend me some references from when I can understand the browser (IE 10) flow of events when a page is loaded?

Comment: Doesn't `window.onload` work for you?

Comment: thanks! but from what I tested, no.